# What does a lifetime reference when declared in a trait implementation?

Tags: rust

I'm learning about named lifetimes in Rust, and I'm having trouble understanding what they represent when they are used in the implementation of a trait. Specifically, I'm having trouble understanding this piece of code from [libserialize/hex.rs](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/blob/168b2d1a3f4569706fe4f9a2baee04e37f85d297/src/libserialize/hex.rs). I've removed some comments for brevity's sake.

```rust
pub trait ToHex {
    fn to_hex(&self) -> ~str;
}

static CHARS: &'static[u8] = bytes!("0123456789abcdef");

impl<'a> ToHex for &'a [u8] {
    fn to_hex(&self) -> ~str {
        let mut v = slice::with_capacity(self.len() * 2);
        for &byte in self.iter() {
            v.push(CHARS[(byte >> 4) as uint]);
            v.push(CHARS[(byte & 0xf) as uint]);
        }

        unsafe {
             str::raw::from_utf8_owned(v)
        }
    }
}
```

I understand the `'static` lifetime in the CHARS definition, but I'm stumped on the lifetime defined in the ToHex implementation. **What do named lifetimes represent in the implementation of a trait?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that particular case—not much. `&[u8]` is not a completely specified type because the lifetime is missing, and implementations must be for fully specified types. Thus, the implementation is parameterised over the arbitrary (for the generic parameter is unconstrained) lifetime `'a`.

In this case, you don't use it again. There are cases where you will, however—when you wish to constrain a function argument or return value to the same lifetime.

You can then write things like this:

```
impl<'a, T> ImmutableVector<'a, T> for &'a [T] {
    fn head(&self) -> Option<&'a T> {
        if self.len() == 0 { None } else { Some(&self[0]) }
    }
    …
}
```

That means that the return value will have the same lifetime as `self`, `'a`.

Incidentally, just to mess things up, the lifetime *could* be written manually on each function:

```
impl<'a, T> ImmutableVector<'a, T> for &'a [T] {
    fn head<'a>(&'a self) -> Option<&'a T> {
        if self.len() == 0 { None } else { Some(&self[0]) }
    }
    …
}
```

… and that demonstrates that having to specify the lifetime of the type that you are implementing for is just so that the type is indeed *fully* specified. And it allows you to write a little bit less for all the functions inside that use that lifetime.

Comment: Awesome, things are making a lot more sense to me now. Am I correct when I say that *all references require a lifetime to be defined*, but that the compiler adds it automatically in certain cases like function arguments? I think that might be the part I was missing.

Comment: Indeed, that is the case. In most places it is automatically determined if not specified, and inside function arguments is such a case.

Comment: Isn't the second example invalid, since the lifetime on the method is shadowing the one on the impl? Besides being illegal in current Rust, it also isn't the same. Or am I wrong? I am new to Rust and haven't fully understood lifetimes yet.

Comment: @jotep: yeah, shadowing became illegal after I wrote this example; I’m not sure about the other part—at one point the two might have been the same, but I would have thought that was earlier; the checking was a little weak at some point in history, so that that worked (presuming it did) was actually a soundness bug.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: The `self` argument on your `head` method is of type `&'b &'a [T]`, where `'b` is either the implicit lifetime in the first code sample or the now invalid `'a` lifetime in the second code sample. Since `'b` outlives `'a`, both lifetimes can legitimately be used on the return value. Of course, the double indirection is unnecessary in this case (the argument could be `self` instead of `&self`).

Comment: @FrancisGagné: good call on the lifetimes; I perceive that it wasn’t a soundness bug then in this particular case, but the fundamental issue that lifetime mismatch was permitted back then was an issue; now in such a case it says “error: method `head` has an incompatible type for trait: expected bound lifetime parameter , found concrete lifetime [E0053]” For `&self` versus `self`, the right solution is to cut out the lifetime altogether and implement on the unsized type.